# Is it safe to set `out=a` in `np.compress`?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I want to compress some subset of a large numpy array along the first dimension, here's an arbitrary example:

```py
a = np.random.normal(size=(100_000, 5))
subset = (np.sum(a, axis=1) > 0)
a_compressed = a.compress(subset, axis=0)
```

Sadly this allocates a new array

```py
assert not np.shares_memory(a, a_compressed)
```

I don't really want to allocate more memory since my array is already quite large. I also don't actually care about `a` after generating `a_compressed`, so I'd like to reuse the array. I found I can do this:

```py
a_compressed = a.compress(subset, axis=0, out=a[:np.sum(subset)])
assert np.shares_memory(a, a_compressed)
```

This seems to work but I can't verify anywhere that this is a legal way of using `out=`. The [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.compress.html#numpy.compress) doesn't mention it, and when I try to follow the source I have a very hard time tracking which function call goes where.

Comment: When I use the wrong size of `out`, I get an error referencing `ndarray.take`, which in my experience is just another way of doing index assignment.  So as long as the `out` has the right size it works.  But is it doing so incrementally, or is there an intermediate buffer.  Incremental take/assign could mess up values, but if it does the whole take into a buffer, and then assigns that to `out`, values should be safe.  `ufunc.at` suggests that most numpy operations are buffered.

Comment: Playing around with a smaller (4,3) array, I believe your use of `out` is the same as `a_compressed = a[:np.sum(subset)] = a.compress(subset, axis=0)`.   It is buffered.